# Creating a Polar plot with magnitude and angle in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Vector plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDTyw.png)

How can I create something like this using Magnitudes and 360° angles in Excel 2016.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for? This is a solution to track "flight paths" from a central point. The data is columns A:C. The rest of the columns are formulas to get things to correctly plot. Granted, it's not a polar chart, but maybe this gives you an idea how to solve.

If this is NOT what you're looking for, then I'll delete this.

If this IS what you're looking for, then I can elaborate on how this works.

[image]

**EDIT**

About these data: Tracking 9 flights from central point. The BEARING column represents the direction, where 0 is due North (staight up the Y axis). From there, it goes clockwise. 90 would be straight east. The RANGE column represents distance traveled in one direction. Then the flight returns back to the central point.

Columns D formula stages a value we need for X.

```
=IF(C4=0,0,IF(C4=90,0,IF(C4=180,0,IF(C4=270,0,IF(C4<91,C4,IF(C4<181,180-C4,IF(C4<271,C4-180,360-C4)))))))

If C is 0, 90, 180 or 270, then 0
If C is < 91, then C value
If C is < 181, then 180 minus C
If C is < 271, then C minus 180
Else 360 minus C
```

Column E formula stages a value we need for Y:

```
=IF(D4=0,0,90-D4)
```

Column F converts angles to points on the X axis:

```
=IF(C4=0,0,IF(C4=90,B4,IF(C4=180,0,IF(C4=270,B4,SIN(RADIANS(D4))*B4))))
```

Column G converts angles to points on the Y axis:

```
=IF(F4=0,B4,SIN(RADIANS(E4))*B4)
```

Column H adjusts points on the X axis to properly reflect positive or negative:

```
=IF(C4<181,F4,0-F4)
```

Column I adjusts points on the Y axis to properly reflect positive or negative:

```
=IF(OR(C4<91,C4>270),G4,0-G4)
```

Lastly, make sure your data is every other row like in the picture. In columns H and I, input 0's for the blank rows. That will take your line back to the central point.

The chart type is an X Y Scatter plot with straight lines (columns H and I).

Comment: yes I think this is what I want to know about

Comment: @Trex Added more information.